# Could add a 'Who is looking at your post' feature

Tags: feature-request

Like the old school forums where there is a list of people currently viewing your post.

Comment: Let me stalk people in private TYVM.

Comment: What would be the benefits offered by that feature? Do you have something specific in mind?

Comment: Even Facebook and Twitter don't allow this (thankfully). Why should we?

Comment: @AndrewBarber actually, Facebook has a feature which lets you know who's ["seen" a post](http://bostinno.streetwise.co/channels/seen-by-the-facebook-feature-that-tells-the-world-if-youve-read-a-post/). It's awful.

Comment: I'm looking at your post.  Now I'm not.  Now I'm looking at it again.  Whoops, now I've moved on.

Comment: Okay for example, 15 people have 'viewed' this post. If I'm looking for someone to help me out on a problem quickly, I can know if there is someone viewing the post who may be likely to post a reply. That way I don't have to linger around the post to see if someone is about to reply. I guess having notifications/the bar that pops up that shows a new comment/reply is similar, but it would be nice

Comment: Those 15 people could all be there to downvote you as well, which then gives you an idea of who downvoted you, which can lead to targeted revenge downvotes, which can lead to ...

Comment: @BlahBlahGrabblesnackers ... *Death!*

Comment: ... Crackers!!!

Comment: Too bad I can only downvote once. I need about 10 to properly convey how ***terrible*** an idea I think this would be.

Comment: @CodyGray `s/10/100/`

Answer (score 10):

I would rather have some privacy.

Showing who is viewing your post could lead to:

- OP requesting (or forcing) the viewers to answer his/her question
- People knowing who cast the upvotes/downvotes

Browsing in private allows us to view questions without any worries. We can always make our own decision on whether or not to respond to a post, either as a comment or an answer.

As the one who posted the question, I would stick around for a while since people here usually give quick responses. There is already a view count for you to judge the likelihood of getting a response. If there aren't any responses for a while, check the notifications later on to see if there is one.

Comment: oh your right, newbies could start spamming for the person to reply i.e. "xxx ur watching, help me out" and stuff like that. bad idea i guess

Comment: Not to mention I and many others often leave tabs open to questions they plan to check back later.